# fe_sendauth: no password supplied on localhost:300

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, localhost

I just installed heroku and then postgresql but now I am getting this error. Why do I need a password? what is my password?

I've spent at a couple of hours looking for something that works but can't get anything to work(I'm on windows):

this is my database.yml

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_development
  pool: 5
  username: postgresql
  password: 
  host: localhost

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_test
  pool: 5
  username: postgresql
  password: 
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: myapp_production
  pool: 5
  username: postgresql
  password: 
  host: localhost
```

This is my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.3'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'devise'


gem 'pg'


group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.1.2'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Any idea of what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your local machine under the `test` and `development` sections of the `database.yml` file you should change the `username` to your logged in username. The rails generator makes it the same as your appname and that will not work. In production it does not matter as you deploy to heroku and that settings is automatically changed.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql), you could use this command:

```
$ heroku config | grep HEROKU_POSTGRESQL
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL: postgres://user3123:passkja83kd8@ec2-117-21-174-214.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6212/db982398
```

The URL given is a [postgresql connection](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) string which contains the username and password embedded in it (user3123 and passkja83kd8 in this example).

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Should I also use the user3123 and passkja83kd8 or do I use different ones. What is my User & password or where do I look to find out? I'm pretty new at rails so have never done this.

Comment: @user3408293 I suggest you read the page I linked - heroku documentation relating to postgresql. If you set up a database in heroku, then heroku should be able to tell you the password it was set up with. The command `heroku config` appears to do that (although note that I don't know anything about heroku so I am just going on the documented heroku help).